# How to 'Combine' list of dates to a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

How do you combine list of date into a date range, I need combine a series of days in different rows into a a date range of start date and end date.

```
Create Table #temp_dates
 (Str_Date DateTime,
 End_Date DateTime,
 Rate decimal(10,4))
 ;

 Insert Into #temp_dates
 Values ('2012-01-05 07:55:24.000','2012-03-03 12:25:02.000',0.001),
('2012-03-03 12:25:02.000','2012-03-04 15:28:16.000',0.001),
('2012-03-04 15:28:16.000','2012-08-23 05:14:07.000',0.001),
('2012-08-23 05:14:07.000','2013-04-24 15:04:25.000',0.001),
('2013-04-24 15:04:25.000','2015-04-13 05:37:59.000',0.0015),
('2015-04-13 05:37:59.000','2015-10-11 08:50:24.000',0.0015),
('2015-10-11 08:50:24.000','2016-03-19 23:58:35.000',0.0015),
('2016-03-19 23:58:35.000','2016-03-20 11:07:56.000',0.001),
('2016-03-20 11:07:56.000','2016-04-12 21:05:06.000',0.0015),
('2016-04-12 21:05:06.000','2016-04-12 22:31:41.000',0.001),
('2016-04-12 22:31:41.000','2016-04-20 00:45:32.000',0.0015),
('2016-04-20 00:45:32.000','2016-09-10 19:17:31.000',0.0015)
```

Turn

```
StartDateTime   EndDateTime Rate
2012-01-05 07:55:24.000 2012-03-03 12:25:02.000 0.001
2012-03-03 12:25:02.000 2012-03-04 15:28:16.000 0.001
2012-03-04 15:28:16.000 2012-08-23 05:14:07.000 0.001
2012-08-23 05:14:07.000 2013-04-24 15:04:25.000 0.001
2013-04-24 15:04:25.000 2015-04-13 05:37:59.000 0.0015
2015-04-13 05:37:59.000 2015-10-11 08:50:24.000 0.0015
2015-10-11 08:50:24.000 2016-03-19 23:58:35.000 0.0015
2016-03-19 23:58:35.000 2016-03-20 11:07:56.000 0.001
2016-03-20 11:07:56.000 2016-04-12 21:05:06.000 0.0015
2016-04-12 21:05:06.000 2016-04-12 22:31:41.000 0.001
2016-04-12 22:31:41.000 2016-04-20 00:45:32.000 0.0015
2016-04-20 00:45:32.000 2016-09-10 19:17:31.000 0.0015
```

Into

```
StartDateTime   EndDateTime Rate
2012-01-05 07:55:24.000 2013-04-24 15:04:25.000 0.001
2013-04-24 15:04:25.000 2016-03-19 23:58:35.000 0.0015
2016-03-19 23:58:35.000 2016-03-20 11:07:56.000 0.001
2016-03-20 11:07:56.000 2016-04-12 21:05:06.000 0.0015
2016-04-12 21:05:06.000 2016-04-12 22:31:41.000 0.001
2016-04-12 22:31:41.000 2016-09-10 19:17:31.000 0.0015
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, use `lag()` to determine where a group begins.  Then use a cumulative sum over these "beginnings" to define the rows you want to group together.

The last step is the actual aggregation:

```
select rate, min(str_date), max(end_date)
from (select td.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date = str_date then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by rate order by str_date) as grp
      from (select td.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by rate order by str_date) as prev_end_date
            from temp_dates td
           ) td
     ) td
group by rate, grp
order by min(str_date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d1deb45f18413c7c8414a12de108d5e) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. You can solve it using a `lag()` and a window sum.

```
select 
    min(StartDateTime) StartDateTime, 
    max(EndDateTime) EndDateTime,
    Rate
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when LagRate = Rate then 0 else 1 end) over(order by StartDateTime) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            lag(Rate) over(order by StartDateTime) LagRate
        from #temp_dates t
    ) t
) t
group by grp, Rate
order by min(StartDateTime)
```

The first subquery associates the previous `Rate` to each record. Then, the next subquery computes the group: everytime the `Rate` changes, a new group starts. Finally, the outer query aggregates the records in each group, and pulls out the minimum `StartDateTime` and the maximum `EndDateTime` of each group, along with the associated `Rate`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=070d6572edcabf926f23c28606882169)**:

```
StartDateTime       | EndDateTime         | Rate  
:------------------ | :------------------ | :-----
05/01/2012 07:55:24 | 24/04/2013 15:04:25 | 0.0010
24/04/2013 15:04:25 | 19/03/2016 23:58:35 | 0.0015
19/03/2016 23:58:35 | 20/03/2016 11:07:56 | 0.0010
20/03/2016 11:07:56 | 12/04/2016 21:05:06 | 0.0015
12/04/2016 21:05:06 | 12/04/2016 22:31:41 | 0.0010
12/04/2016 22:31:41 | 10/09/2016 19:17:31 | 0.0015
```